# executing spring roo programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

i had a look at spring roo.I found that we can generate entities ,contollers and others using command prompt. But i need to get the entity names and field names as a user input from text boxes and then generate the project using roo. I am using windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Roo Command Wizard available on the Springsource Tool Suite (STS).

Answer (score 5):

You can create script file, and then execute that file with roo.

```
>roo script --file fileName.
```

Unfortunaly I do not know if it is possible to run roo with the script as an parameter so that it automaticaly run that script.

Answer (score 0):

The latest roo (I have 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT [rev 7a0fe1b]) has a fledgling web interface called Eastern Grey UI (http://localhost:9191).  I'm finding you can call the functions like this (a test module I'm working on  -- service.post just does a standard post to a web site):

```
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
    env.put("projectName", "clinic");
    env.put("topLevelPackage", "com.ritchey");
    String resp = service.post("http://localhost:9191/rs-api/project", env);
    log.debug("resp = " + resp);

    env = new HashMap<String, String>();
    env.put("database", "MSSQL");
    env.put("providerName", "HIBERNATE");
    env.put("username", "Avatar");
    env.put("password", "xxxxxx");
    resp = service.post("http://localhost:9191/rs-api/persistence", env);
    log.debug("resp = " + resp);

    env = new HashMap<String, String>();
    env.put("entityName", "~.domain.Pet");
    resp = service.post("http://localhost:9191/rs-api/entities", env);
    log.debug("resp = " + resp);

    env = new HashMap<String, String>();
    env.put("entityName", "~.domain.Pet");
    env.put("fieldName", "name");
    env.put("fieldGroup", "");
    env.put("fieldType", "string");
    env.put("referencedClass", "");
    resp = service.post("http://localhost:9191/rs-api/fields", env);
    log.debug("resp = " + resp);
```