# How to put comment in Spring Roo script file when scripting a batch execution?

Tags: batch-file, comments, spring-roo

We can use Roo's `script` command to run a Roo batch execution as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9325344/248616)

> roo> script --file filename

My question is in `filename` script content, how can I put a comment line/block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put comment on roo script like the syntax of single line comment of Java.

```
// Your comment here
// another comment
```

p.s.

We may also use `/* .... */` block though it is applied on one line only.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `//` and `/*`, you can use also `#` at the beginning of the line